# Not able to get value from select element. (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the value of a drop down menu. The drop down menu is created after a user clicks the button `With Undrafted Players` . However, when I echo `selectOptionud`, I do not get any value. Any idea what's going on here?

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submitundrafted'])) {

            $selectOptionud = $_POST['filter_ud']; //undrafted selection 

            echo $selectOptionud;
        }//end of submitundrafted


if (isset($_POST['undrafted'])) {   

                $menu= "<select name='filter_ud' id='filter_ud'>
                            " . $options . " //I have erased the previous code that gets the value of this variable.
                     </select>";

                echo $menu;
                ?>
                <form action="transfer.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="submitundrafted" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <?php

        }
?>
<form action="transfer.php" method="post"> 

   <input type="submit" name="undrafted" value="With Undrafted Players">                

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are echoing `$menu` ( or `<select name='filter_ud' id='filter_ud'>`) before your `<form>` open tag, so it will not be posted. Place the `echo $menu;` inside your `<form>` tags

Comment: I initially did not have the `<form>` within the `<form>`. I just added it to see if it would fix the problem I am currently having.

Comment: and where is the value of $options  ?

Comment: The echo `$menu` is for the drop down menu that seems to work fine. I'm having a problem with echoing `selectOptionud`

Comment: I removed the value of `$options` for this question. It is in my original code though.

Comment: first u need to print_r( $options) before isset condition and check your $options is empty or not.

Comment: Your issue with `echo $selectOptionud;` is related to your `echo $menu;`. Doing `... echo $menu; ?> <form ...> .... </form>` is wrong as the `<select>` element is not in the form. Doing `<form ...> <?php echo $menu; ?>.... </form>`, is the correct way, as it is inside the `<form>` tags, and will then be available.

Answer (score 0):

here `$options` will be like this

```
<option value="1">abc</option>
<option value="2">bcd</option>
<option value="3">def</option>

     if (isset($_POST['undrafted'])) {   
        $menu= "<select name='filter_ud' id='filter_ud'>
                                    " . $options . " //I have erased the previous code that gets the value of this variable.
                 </select>";
     ?>
     <form action="transfer.php" method="post">
        <?php echo $menu;?>
        <input type="submit" name="submitundrafted" value="Submit" />
     </form>
     <?php
      }?>
```